# Inserting different item types in composite collection

Tags: c#, wpf

This may be an obvious question, but I have never used CompositeCollection before. Is it possible to initially populate a CompositeCollection with one type of items, and then use Insert method to insert items of different type at some random indexes? Or maybe I am completely missing the concept of composite collection as it is intended to store multiple observable collections of different types?

Comment: As I understand the documentation, it is intended to aggregate multiple collections into one. The items/collections aggregated may have different types. Check this MSDN example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742405(v=vs.110).aspx . It might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi yes what you want to do is absolutely possible.

```
Insert(Int32, Object)
```

Inserts an item in the collection at a given index. All items after the given position are moved down by one. So you can initially populate your compositecollection and then later add new elements of different types to random positions.

Here's the complete reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.110).aspx